# bin folder not found in Magento (1.9.2.4)

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm working with the old version of Magento (1.9.2.4). And the problem, it would seem, is very trivial, but there is no "bin" folder.

Comment: What do you expect to find in this "bin" folder ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no bin folder in Magento 1.9.2.4. See [this GitHub page for more information](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror).